# Confusion regarding change of variable and irreducibility

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, algebraic-groups, invariant-theory

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristics zero. Let $X$ be an irreducible affine variety, with a rational action of a linearly reductive algebraic group $G$. Also, assume that $\mathbb{K}[X]$ is a UFD.

Let $U\subseteq X$ be a $G$-stable open subset of $X$ such the geometric quotient $\Phi: U\rightarrow W$ exists, and it's given by $u\mapsto \left(\frac{f_1f_2(u)}{f_3f_4(u)},\frac{f_5f_2(u)}{f_3f_6(u)}\right)$, where $u\in U$ and $f_i$'s $\in\mathbb{K}[X]$ are irreducible elements and non-zero on $U$. So, I can realize $W$ as a closed subset in $\mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{P}^1$ via the morphism $u\mapsto \left(\left[1:\frac{f_1f_2(u)}{f_3f_4(u)}\right],\left[1:\frac{f_5f_2(u)}{f_3f_6(u)}\right]\right)$, and the image will, in fact, lie inside $\mathbb{A}^{1}\times\mathbb{A}^{1}\cong \mathbb{A}^{2}$.

Now, take $V:=\mathcal{V}(y-2x)\subseteq \mathbb{A}^{2}$, and suppose I know that $\mathcal{V}(h)=\Phi^{-1}(V)$, for some irreducible $h\in\mathbb{K}[X]$.

> How do I find $h$?

> Do I just need to replace $x$ by $\frac{f_1f_2}{f_3f_4}$, and $y$ by $\frac{f_5f_2}{f_3f_6}$, and then clear out the denominator to get $h$(up to associates)?

But, if I do that then I get $f_5f_2f_3f_4-2f_1f_2f_3f_6$, which is clearly not irreducible since $f_2f_3$ divides it.

What am I missing?

Comment: There's a lot to unpack here, but you start with: "Let $U \subseteq X$ be …", and then list some conditions.  Is it clear that those conditions can be satisfied?

Comment: @LSpice The situation I'm interested in has all these conditions satisfied

Comment: There is no contradiction if $V(f_2)=V(f_3)=\emptyset$. (Indeed $f_3\neq0$ for all $u\in U$, should almost follow from the fact that it appears in the denominator of a regular map $\Phi\colon U\to W$. Perhaps you can show $f_2\neq0$ similarly.)

Comment: @TomDucat So basically after making the substitution for $x$ and $y$, and clearing out the denominator, I have to simply the expression, and then whatever expression I get is associate to $h$, is that right?

Comment: It seems so, since $$u\in \Phi^{-1}(V) \iff \Phi(u)\in V \iff (f_1f_2f_3^{-1}f_4^{-1}, f_5f_2f_3^{-1}f_6^{-1})\in V\iff (f_1f_2f_3^{-1}f_4^{-1} = 2f_5f_2f_3^{-1}f_6^{-1}).$$ Since the $f_i$ are all nonzero on $U$ I can multiply them out. (Sorry, I had missed that you already specified all $f_i\neq0$ on $U$ when I wrote my last comment, so the part in the brackets is irrelevant.)